# Awk output to shell variable with shell variable as search pattern

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to find (with awk) the IP of a specific ethernet interface using the hostname as a search patter (suffixed by the name of the ethernet interface). I wrote this little script but it outputs nothing and I don't understand why...

```
#!/bin/bash
name=$(hostname -s)-eth3
IP1=`awk -v var=$name '/var/ {print $1}' /etc/hosts`
echo $IP1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please make few changes as shown following, which may help you.

```
#!/bin/bash
name=$(hostname -s)-eth3
IP1=$(awk -v var=$name '$0 ~ var{print $1}' "/etc/hosts")
echo "$IP1"
```

changes like backtick is not encouraged for storing values in bash variables `$` should be used and use `echo "$var"` too.

Answer (score 0):

Inside slashes, awk treats `var` as a literal string, not a variable. 
 Thus, replace:

```
/var/
```

With:

```
$0 ~ var
```

Thus use:

```
#!/bin/bash
name=$(hostname -s)-eth3
ip1=`awk -v var=$name '$0 ~ var {print $1}' /etc/hosts`
echo "$ip1"
```

#### Example

The first awk script below produces no match but the second does:

```
$ echo host-eth1 | awk -v var='host-eth1' '/var/ {print $1}'
$ echo host-eth1 | awk -v var='host-eth1' '$0 ~ var {print $1}'
host-eth1
```